# Allowing POST requests from specific domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to restrict all POST request which are not coming from my domains. Only allow my 3 domains and localhost.

I tried below code in `.htaccess` file of wordpress. But this block all including my domains.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !http://webone.com
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !https://webtwo.com
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !http://webthree.com
 RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
 </IfModule>
```

How to allow mine and restrict others domains request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access from localhost without restrictions since `%{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1` is false. `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` reflects - as the name says - the address, that's the IP address.

If you cannot identify your trusted hosts by IP for some reason, use `%{REMOTE_HOST}` instead to evaluate hosts by name. To get this to wörk, `HostnameLookups` must be turned `On`. It is `Off` by default since it enables reverse DNS lookups which result in performance issues.

Even better would be using `RewriteMap` in the server or virtual-host config.